# Why wont the DataContext collection refresh after insertion?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I've the following BLL class, which provides tools for adding, updating and deleting elements of a specific type in the db:

```
public class Asset
{
    private Data.DicDataContext _db;
    public Asset(int assetID)
{
    _db = new Data.DicDataContext();
    _asset = _db.Assets.First(a => a.id == assetID);
}
    public static Asset New(int assetTypeID, int containerID)
{
        Asset nAsset;
        using (Data.DicDataContext db = new Data.DicDataContext())
        {
            Data.Asset asset = new Data.Asset();

            asset.typeID = assetTypeID;
            asset.containerID = containerID;
            asset.createdDate = DateTime.Now;

            Data.User user = (Data.User)db.Users.First(u => u.id == Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]));

            user.Assets.Add(asset);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            nAsset = new Asset(asset.id);
        }
        return nAsset;
}
}
```

The problem arises, when I add a new element to the db with Asset.New(). The element is correctly saved in the db, but when I try to collect the newly added element with the new Asset() contructor, the element isn't found in the sequence.

Any help would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code so it looks like this.

```
public Asset(int assetID)
{
   using (Data.DicDataContext db = new Data.DicDataContext())
    {
        _asset = db.Assets.First(a => a.id == assetID);
    }
}
```

Please note it is not really a good practice to keep the connection open so take out your reference to the `Data.DicDataContext()`

this line `private Data.DicDataContext _db;`

You must have a `using` in every method. Just like in your New Method.

Comment: Just a quick correction, I think you meant to say db.Assets, not _db.Assets as _db should be removed as you've stated.

Comment: @Richard, thats correct, sorry will fix now. Copying and pasting. :P

Comment: @Jethro, thanks for your quick answer! Kinda hard to leave the good ol' reuse everything politic. Next newb question though - how do I permanently save _asset? It only seems to save a reference to the Asset and when I close DC the reference is gone.

Comment: Well went back to the drawing board and came up with an entirely different approach for our BBL pattern. Thanks for your help